# R: How to delete words other than specific words in a corpus

Tags: r, text-mining, corpus

In the corpus "tkn_pb" , I would like to delete all words except for some keywords I chose (ex. "attack" and "gunman"). Is it possicle to do this?

[image]

Comment: To make your code easier to reproduce, please paste your code into your question, it isbetter than doing a screenshot of it

Comment: I'll do so from now on. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: Regular expressions can be slow. `dplyr::anti_join` or `dplyr::filter` + `%in%` might be useful. Hard to say without example data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `which`and `grepl` to subset your corpus:

Data:

```
sample_tokens <- c("word", "another","a", "new", "word token", "one", "more", "and", "another one")
```

Remove all words except "a" and "and":

```
sample_tokens[which(grepl("\\b(a|and)\\b", sample_tokens))]
[1] "a"   "and"
```

**EDIT**:

If the corpus is a list, then this solution suggested by @John would work:

Data:

```
sample_tokens <- list(c("word", "another","a", "new", "word token", "one", "more", "and", "another one"),
               c("yet", "a", "few", "more", "words"),
               c("and", "so on"))

lapply(sample_tokens, function(x) x[which(grepl("\\b(a|and)\\b", x))])
[[1]]
[1] "a"   "and"

[[2]]
[1] "a"

[[3]]
[1] "and"
```

Comment: It looks like a list-like object in the question - for which you could extend the above answer by using: `lapply(sample_tokens, function(x){ x[which(grepl("\\b(a|and)\\b", x))]})`